# Proof Complex Number Square Roots

Tags: complex-numbers, alternative-proof

I need to be able to prove that there are always two square roots of a non-zero complex number, though I'm uncertain as to how I prove this. When I tried doing it algebraically letting $(a+ib)^2 = x+iy$, then getting various simultaneous equations, I end up getting 4 potential roots with all the plus's and minuses.

How do you prove this algebraically?

Is there another method of proving it that is simpler and quicker?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your four different solutions, because otherwise we will not be able to say if  two of them are the same or not.

Comment: I suspect if you get four solutions that you are somehow adding extraneous solutions.  You should have $a^2 -b^2 = x$ and $2ab = y$ so $a$  and $b$ are must be either opposite signs or the same signs (depending on whether y is pos or neg).  I suspect in solving fo $a^2 - b^2 = x$ you are allowing a and b to be either neg or positive for two extraneous posibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding your expression:

$$a^2+2abi-b^2=x+iy$$

Comparing real and imaginary parts:

$$a^2-b^2=x\text{ and }2ab=y$$

$$(a^2-b^2)^2+(2ab)^2=x^2+y^2$$

$$a^4-2a^2b^2+b^4+4a^2b^2=x^2+y^2$$

$$a^4+2ab+b^4=x^2+y^2$$

$$(a^2+b^2)^2=x^2+y^2$$

$$a^2+b^2=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

Note: The negative root can be ignored as $a^2+b^2\ge0$

$$a^2=\frac{1}{2}\left(a^2+b^2+a^2-b^2\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x\right)$$

$$b^2=\frac{1}{2}\left(a^2+b^2-(a^2-b^2)\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x\right)$$

Looking at the right hand side of both these equations the values are both positive so a square root is possible of both:

$$a=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x\right)}$$

$$b=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x\right)}$$

Now while there are four combinations we know that $2ab=y$ so two of these combinations would be invalid as the product of $ab$ must have the same sign as $y$.

Comment: For the first part, how did you get $a^2-2abi-b^2$?

Comment: I think it's just  a typo. It should be $a^2+2abi-b^2$.

Comment: Err yeh. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

You don't give much context, but if you know (or can assume) the [fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) that any $n^{th}$ degree polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[X]$ has exactly $n$ roots (counting multiplicity) then the existence of exactly $2$ complex square roots of $c = x+iy$ follows from FTA for $z^2-c=0$.

Comment: Does FTA apply even if the constant term is a complex number?

Comment: Yes. FTA applies to polynomials with complex coefficients, and the constant term is nothing but one of those coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

Using the polar form $z=re^{i\theta}$ makes it easy.  You get two roots with the angles different by $\pi$ because $2 \pi i=1$.  Your approach should work, but if we don't see your work we can't say what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Write your number in the polar form $re^{i\theta}$ instead of the rectangular form $a+ib.$